# Id in reference to all other other ids in a database

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a row in sqlalchemy that will be like I guess you could call it an universal id. This id would link up with all other ids from the same class (Item) so I will be able to know which items were created before which.

[image: Where item class is located]

It needs to be so when a a new Item is created no matter in what parent class the universal_id will grow by one so if there is a grand total of 10 items in the whole database and a new one is created the universal_id for the 11th item would be 11.

Comment: If the universal id is, in fact, universally unique, then why would you need an item_id as well? Shouldn't the universal id become the item id?

Comment: Good point, I guess I would then only need the universal. How can I make it go up based on all the total items?